# How to detect outgoing call states in android using broadcast receiver on Oreo and above?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, outgoing-call

Can anyone provide me sample code for detecting outgoing call state on Android Oreo and Above ?

My code is working fine up to android 6 but not working on Android 8.1 and Android 9. Almost all answers on stack overflow are consisting deprecated code.

Manifest is having necessary permissions and doesn't have any registered receiver as per guidelines by Google

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    private static Date callStartTime;
    private static boolean isIncoming;
    private static String savedNumber;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
            savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");

        } else {
            String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            int state = 0;
            if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
            } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
            }

            onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
        }
    }
        public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
            if(lastState == state){
                //No change, debounce extras
                return;
            }
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    isIncoming = true;
                    callStartTime = new Date();
                    savedNumber = number;

                    Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming Call Ringing" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
                    if(lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                        isIncoming = false;
                        callStartTime = new Date();
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Outgoing Call Started" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
                    if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                        //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing but no pickup" + savedNumber + " Call time " + callStartTime +" Date " + new Date() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else if(isIncoming){

                        Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming " + savedNumber + " Call time " + callStartTime  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Outgoing "+ savedNumber + " Call time " + callStartTime +" Date " + new Date() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                        
                    }

                    break;
            }
            lastState = state;
        }

}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CallReceiver callReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        callReceiver = new CallReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
        filter.addAction("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
        registerReceiver(callReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        try {

            unregisterReceiver(callReceiver);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```